# How to move toward Dev Ops in testing from Agile

Tags: automated-testing, agile-testing, qa-developer, agile, agile-testing-quadrants

We are looking to move towards DevOps methodology. Currently, we are using Agile methodologies in testing. We, as a team wants to increase the number of deployments/releases in a year. For this, we want to reduce our QA Efforts. We want to create our Automation Scripts for System testing the time, our Developers are creating the UI.

Can anyone please let us know the path which we should use?

Comment: a lot more relevant in devops.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the same applies to any technological change. It's usually a good idea to start a PBI for a 'proof of concept' for the new technology, to see if it will be able to do what the team would like it to do. If the proof of concept is successful, you would then determine what specific tasks have to be carried out in order to successfully implement the technology and add those to the product backlog, after which the team can take them into the sprint backlog as they would any other PBI.

If you're looking for instructions on which tools your team should implement and how I don't think that's within the scope of this site or indeed any part of StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

Testing in Agile or "DevOps" is not significantly different from each other. A team identifying as DevOps is probably looking for even more rapid deployment, but it's the same automation and collaboration techniques you'd be using in a team using Agile without DevOps, just more so.